# Display table in correct subsection

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

In my example I have two subsections. Each of them contains single table. I need each table to be displayed under the correct heading.

Now I have:
1. text of subsection C
2. text of subsection E
3. table D
4. table F

I want the order to be:
1. text of subsection C
2. table D 
3. text of subsection E 
4. table F

I don't care if there would be half page blank.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{B}
\subsection{C}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a
\end{tabular}
\caption{D}
\end{table}

\subsection{E}
\lipsum[2-4]
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b
\end{tabular}
\caption{F}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `placeins` package and its `\FloatBarrier` macro.

Comment: Isn't using `\clearpage` simplier?

Comment: If you don't care about half-blank pages, yes.